$f$ with an essential singularity at $0$ intersects $1/z^4$ in every neighborhood of $0$.
This question is from a qual in complex analysis at my Uni, and I feel like I'm losing my mind. My solution seems far too simple for it to be a qual question, and it makes me feel like I must be wrong.
The question: Let $f:\mathbb{D}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and have an essential singularity at $0$. Show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $z$ near $0$ such that $|f(z)-1/z^4|\le \epsilon$.
Proof: Big Picard. Choose any $r>0$, consider $B_r(0)-\{0\}=B_r(p)'$, and let $g(z)=1/z^4$. Let $y \in g(B_r(0)')$. If $y \not \in f(B_r(0)')$, there there exists $y \ne z \in g(B_r(0)')$, and since $f(B_r(0)')$ omits at most one point from $\mathbb{C}$ by Big Picard, $z \in f(B_r(0)')$. In this case, $|f(z)-g(z)|=0\le \epsilon$ for any chosen $\epsilon$.
This seems far too easy to appear on a qual exam. Moreover, the whole "epsilon" business makes me suspicious. Why state it that way? While true, if I'm correct, we don't need to even worry about epsilon. We can just say show $f$ intersects $g$ in every deleted neighborhood of $0$.

$z$ is an element of the image of $g$, it may not even be near $0$.
Nonetheless, the proof is still not very difficult.
As $\dfrac{1}{z^4}$ has a pole at $0$, $f(z)-\dfrac{1}{z^4}$ has an essential singularity. By Picard's Great Theorem, $f(z)-\dfrac{1}{z^4}$ takes on all complex values, except maybe one, on every neighbourhood of $0$. Thus, we can always find small enough $z$ such that $\left|f(z)-\dfrac{1}{z^4}\right|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.
For a counterexample to the intersection of $f$ and $\dfrac{1}{z^4}$, consider $f(z)=e^{1/z}+\dfrac{1}{z^4}$, which has an essential singularity at $0$. As the exponential never vanishes, $f$ and $\dfrac{1}{z^4}$ can not intersect.
